# Command line replacement for tmutil

Tags: backup, command-line, time-machine

Anyone know of a command line replacement for tmutil, either script or binary?

Failures of tmutil:

- Does not log.
- No meaningful diagnostics.
- Cannot resume interrupted restore.
- Cannot overwrite existing destination.
- Does not recover gracefully from errors.
- Does not handle the restoration from case sensitive TM volume to case insensitive destination.

Comment: If you're using Time Machine you're stuck with it. There are other back up options though, like Carbon Copy Cloner etc. Though I don't think any of the come with a CLI tool.